# Excel vba for a range on column A copy the values of the different columns

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a new access database to import the data I manage in excel for the test results of several users.However the excel file I have due to the layout and the number of columns and files, is really hard to prepare the file for import manually. This is why I have been looking for any vba code to make the work :)

The file have in the column A the test references and then in each column it have the name of one user and the respective scores for each test. I need to copy for each user's name and all the test references and scores in consequent blocks so just using 3 columns, one for user's name, then test refence and finally the test score.

I think it is not so clear (but cannot explain better, sorry), so let me upload 2 pics of examples of current sheet data and how data should look after run the code.

Thanks so much in advance

#### Current sheet data

[image: IMG1]

#### How data should look after run the code

[image: IMG2]

Comment: can you post what you have tried?

Comment: Sorry but I have not done any attempt to automate that as basically I don't have vba/macro knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, this should be able to loop through like you're looking for. It's a little bit rigid because I don't really know much about your book layout. Right now, it assumes that `Sheets(1)` is the source and `Sheets(2)` is your destination.

```
Sub test()

    Dim lastCol As Long
    lastCol = Sheets(1).Cells(2, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Dim col As Long
    For col = 2 To lastCol
        userLoop (col)
    Next col

End Sub

Sub userLoop(ByVal col As Long)

    Dim lastRow_sheet1 As Long
    lastRow_sheet1 = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row

    Dim lastRow_sheet2 As Long
    lastRow_sheet2 = Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row + 1
    If lastRow_sheet2 = 1 Then lastRow_sheet2 = 2

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To lastRow_sheet1
        With Sheets(2)
            .Cells(lastRow_sheet2, "A").Value2 = Sheets(1).Cells(1, col).Value2
            .Cells(lastRow_sheet2, "B").Value2 = Sheets(1).Cells(i, "A").Value2
            .Cells(lastRow_sheet2, "C").Value2 = Sheets(1).Cells(i, col).Value2
        End With

        lastRow_sheet2 = lastRow_sheet2 + 1
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: WOW thank you very much @Marcucciboy2 .. This made the work. I have had just to made a couple of modifications to point to the right column and rows but it perfectly worked :)

Comment: @DavidR thanks for the heads up, made those changes :)